# SignalR long living connections

Tags: c#, websocket, signalr

I am trying to determine if SignalR is the right solution for my application. I have a service that I want to expose which will allow clients to subscribe to an event. It is likely that the event will not fire very often. Is there a best way to configure SignalR to reduce maintenance like handling time outs and such.

**Side Notes**

- Event may not fire for many days and even months
- Client and server may not interact very often.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR is designed to abstract away all the low-level details like timeouts, polling and keep-alives.  However, it will depend on the server being continuously accessible from the client, and it does impose some per-client overhead on the server.  If events are rare, latency is not critical and/or you have to support a very large number of clients, you might prefer some cloud-hosted solution like Amazon SNS.  For notifications to mobile clients, SNS supports the mobile-os-specific notification systems from Apple and Google.

Comment: My goal is to provide a company wide service that notifies subscribers when there is a change in our system. 

I think the concept of push notification is much more fitting. I'm trying to determine if SignalR is still fitting for this because typically SignalR is used for relatively active connections.

Comment: @DavidPrice - So lots of intermittently connected clients, latency not critical.  SNS (or equvalent from other cloud vendors) sounds ideal for that use case. SignalR is probably too "heavy"